# What is a real purpose of dynamic linking in c++?

Tags: c++, c, dll, static-libraries, dynamic-library

I'm new to this and don't understand why I should use `dynamic linking` when there is `static linking`.

1. I know that `dynamic linking` reduces the size of the program file, but if it is a `custom dynamic library`, it will still have to be included in the installer. So, the final size of the app folder will not change.
2. If the external library is already installed on the machine, how to determine and specify its location in the project settings (vs, cmake, qmake). During `dynamic loading` you can find out the location through system calls or Windows Registry. But how to do it during `dynamic linking`?

Please help me, because of these two points I don't understand why `dynamic linking` is needed at all (I can understand the need for `dynamic loading`).

Comment: When you say "dynamic linking" what do you mean by that? A build-time linking to a *shared* library (hint about what many considers its main use-case)? Or run-time loading with e.g. the WINAPI `LoadLibrary` function?

Comment: If you're building a single application then yes, there's probably no benefit to dynamic linking to your libraries

Comment: under "dynamic linking" I mean a build-time linking to a shared library

Comment: https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: You ship all your libraries with the executable, but link dynamically. This lets your user update the libraries if they need to.

Comment: In addition to @HolyBlackCat reason (one could update just the library), there are many others. For start, you seem to believe that "shared library" is the exception and that general case are to artificially split a proprietary application into several libraries that are used only by that application. That is really not the general case, and not the reason why dynamic libraries are made for.

Comment: But even in that case, many applications come with some utilitaries. A browser comes with some external tool to handle bookmarks. I count 6 executables with my `firefox` installation. It is not a bad idea that those 6 executables do not all have a whole copy of the  functions that they certainly partly share.

Comment: Note that nobody here is claiming a dogma "static libraries are bad". There are some good reason to prefer them sometimes. For example the one you refer too (even if you do so seeming to believe that those reasons always apply): if you code a function that will be used only for a unique program, with no plan to propose dfferent implementation (eg one using GPU another CPU) of that function, no plan to particularly update often that function (and distribute without redistributing the whole program), then, static linking is probably to consider.

Comment: I would even argue that there is a modern paradox about libraries: we invented (not so long ago;  I clearly remember when they were a new thing) dynamic libraries. And then we invented `flatpacks` to distribute programs with all their libraries in a single package. And since they have their own copy, own version of the library, in their own sandbox, no chance of memory/disk share with other programs on the machine using the same library. Even worse, of course, when we then `dockerize` those applications.

Comment: So sure, it is legitimate to wonder with those modern usages: wouldn't it be easier to compile a big fat static executable with no dependancies whatsoever, and every code copied inside the executable?

Comment: Why the certain C++ question is tagged with [tag:C]?

Comment: Dynamic libraries allow your executable to be split into smaller pieces which allows the OS to more easily swap out your executable to the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to this and don't understand why I should use `dynamic linking`
> when there is `static linking`.

Note well that that static libraries and (therefore) static linking are the more traditional approach.  Shared libraries and dynamic linking were devised and became overwhelmingly popular for a few main reasons:

1. Reduced **storage size** for applications relative to linking libraries statically
2. Reduced **memory footprint** for applications relative to linking libraries statically
3. Ability to fix bugs and make improvements **once for all** applications

Additionally,

4. some shared-object systems provide for whole applications to be shared objects, which extends the memory footprint advantage to cases of multiple instances of the application running concurrently.
5. some shared-library systems also provide additional features  specific to shared libraries (dynamic loading, weak symbols, *etc*).

---

The primary advantages of static libs revolve primarily around control:

- if an application doesn't want to be dependent on the host system to provide a particular shared library, or
- if an application wants to control the specific version of the library code for compatibility or security purposes

then linking library code statically can address those issues.

---

> 1. I know that `dynamic linking` reduces the size of the program file, but if it is a `custom dynamic library`, it will still have to
>    be included in the installer. So, the final size of the app folder
>    will not change.

Maybe.  But what if your project provides more than one executable depending on the library?  That's not so uncommon, and in that case, making the library a dynamically-linked one *does* save space on your persistent storage device.

And even if you have only one executable, making it use shared libraries and / or be a shared object itself reduces the amount of memory required to run multiple instances concurrently.

In any case, if you're focusing on a custom library that you provide yourself then you should evaluate whether to structure it as a dynamic or static one based on your reasons for building a library in the first place.  For example, if that's purely a convenience for structuring the build of a single executable, then probably it should be a static library -- but you might still want the overall executable to be a dynamic object.

On the other hand, if multiple executables will link the library, and especially if you intend to expose it for use by third-party applications, then you should probably provide a shared library version of it.  You might choose to provide a static library version as well.

> 2. If the external library is already installed on the machine, how to determine and specify its location in the project settings (vs, cmake, qmake). During `dynamic loading` you can find out the location through system calls or Windows Registry. But how to do it during `dynamic linking`?

If it's installed in one of the places that the linker searches by default, then you don't need to locate it manually.  If not, then the link-time problem is no different for dynamically-linked libraries than for statically-linked ones.  When you have that problem then details of how you might solve it depend on OS and build framework.  If you're using CMake, for example, then the shared library distribution can make provision for that (and many do) by providing CMake macros for determining library and header locations, among other details.

In any case, build details are something that relatively few people have to sort out, very few times.  The operational pros and cons discussed at the beginning of this answer are at a much larger scale.

---

Of course, all of the above supposes that you have a choice at all.  Not all systems offer one.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic linking not only reduces the file size of your final executable, but it also improves the memory footprint of your application. If you have two applications, both that are statically linked and both use a common, shared library, then two copies of that same shared library will reside in memory, which is a waste. In general you will always want dynamic linking to produce the smallest and most efficient code.

So when is it appropriate to use static linking? Well if you're unsure of the target machine's OS version, statically linking your application can ensure that your application runs regardless of their version. Also, secure applications, such as financial applications, are a good candidate because it isolates one process from another by providing each an independent environment and no code is shared between any applications. Further on, static linking offers faster execution because we copy the entire library content at compile time. Hence, we don’t have to run the query for unresolved symbols at runtime. Thus, we can execute a statically linked program faster than a dynamically linked one.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where two programs use the same library if the product is basically released in one instance from the company. 
Could you also explain my second point? I still don't understand how you can access an external library with dynamic linking (find the location on another machine) via config files (such as vs settings, cmake, qmake)

Comment: @tomeadom - lots of programs use shared libraries. For example, if you wrote your application in C or C++ using Microsoft's C/C++ compiler, then the standard library would be a shared library. To answer your second question, the linker embeds information about shared libraries in your final executable. At runtime, in Windows, Windows searches for these DLL files in common places such as C:\Windows\System32 or in your path.

Comment: the shared memory argument only really applies in the case of system libraries (or maybe in the case of multiple applications from a single install which share libraries)

Comment: @tomeadom you seem to overestimate the amount of dynamic libraries that are just "private" libraries for the sole purpose of a single application. Most libraries (at least, in linux world) are shared. Some of them, sure, have just the ambition to be shared, and are used in reality only by the single application from their author.

Comment: @tomeadom As for your other question (how to find libraries at compile time): the same way you find static libraries. Tell the compiler where to search them. With GCC, that is via `-L` option, or `LIBRARY_PATH` variable (not to be confused with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is where the system search for dynamic libraries at runtime). Since your whole question seem to be inspired by the idea that dynamic libraries pose problems that static libraries don't. it quite strange to focus on the aspect that is identical between both: where to find them at compile time.

Comment: @chrslg About your last comment. I mean that finding static lib is easy because it is already embedded into project, so it is just a relative path in config file. But what path will be for external lib which can be located anywhere.

Comment: @tomeadom but this has nothing to do with being static or dynamic. Internal libraries of your project, static or dynamic, are "easy to find", since you know where in your project path to find them. External libraries, static or dynamic, need to be stored in some well known global path, and your compiler needs to be informed about where to find them, since that is "system dependent" not "project dependent". Hence `-L` or `LIBRARY_PATH` already mentioned. Needed for both static and dynamic external libraries.

Comment: @tomeadom Once again, you seem to confuse "static/dynamic" dichotomy with "owned by project / external" dichotomy. Those are two totally different considerations. And all 4 combinations exist.